# Using Twython or Tweepy to check if a Tweet is a reply?

Tags: python, twitter, wrapper, tweepy, twython

Is there a way, given a tweet ID, to check if a tweet is a reply rather than an original tweet? If so, is there a way to get the ID of the tweet that the original tweet is in reply to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [Twitter Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) you see that a tweet object has

> in_reply_to_status_id
>
> Nullable. If the represented Tweet is a reply, this field will contain the integer representation of the original Tweet’s ID.
>
> Example: "in_reply_to_status_id":114749583439036416

Using tweepy you can do something like this:

```
user_tweets = constants.api.user_timeline(user_id=user_id, count=100)

    for tweet in user_tweets:
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            # Tweet is a reply
            is_reply = True
        else:
            # Tweet is not a reply
            is_reply = False
```

If you're looking for a specific tweet and you have the id then you want to use [get_status](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#status-methods) like this:

```
tweet = constants.api.get_status(tweet_id)

if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
    # Tweet is a reply
    is_reply = True
else:
    # Tweet is not a reply
    is_reply = False
```

Where `api` is:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Comment: Does this check through the entire user timeline? I'm trying to test particular tweets.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the relevant information.

Comment: You the best!!!!! - you wouldn't happen to know if there's a way to get the ID of the tweet the reply was originally in response to??

Comment: tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is either None or the id of the tweet they replied to.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHH YEEEEEAAAAHHHHH!!!!!!!! You're 100% right!!! Thank you so much bud!