# How to identify if a particular tweet is a reply or a new mention?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to make a bot that replies whoever mentions it, but I want to put an if statement to check if the mentioning is a reply of a tweet (that originally mentioned my @)

This is my code -

```
import tweepy
import time
from datetime import datetime


# Connecting to Twitter API
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Message to reply with if someone mentions the bot
message = "Hi, Thank you so much for reaching TalkyTweety Out :) Please reply to continue this conversation. "

# Bot's unique ID
client_id = client.get_me().data.id

# This is so the bot only looks for the most recent tweets.
start_id = 1
initialisation_resp = client.get_users_mentions(client_id)

if initialisation_resp.data != None:
    start_id = initialisation_resp.data[0].id

# Looking for mentions tweets in an endless loop
while True:
    response = client.get_users_mentions(client_id, since_id=start_id)
    # Reply Code
    if response.data != None:
        for tweet in response.data:
            try:
                print(tweet.text)
            
                client.create_tweet(in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet.id, text=message)
                start_id = tweet.id
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

    # Delay (so the bot doesn't search for new tweets a bunch of times each second)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I've tried using the resources from this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468267/using-twython-or-tweepy-to-check-if-a-tweet-is-a-reply) but it doesn't work. It simply doesn't executes - in_reply_to_status_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "expansions" parameter from get_users_mentions, you can get additional information about the tweet and filter if the tweet has any mention

Documentation:

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_mentions
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/expansions_and_fields.html#expansions-parameter

Comment: I tried but I don't know where I can use the expansion parameters, should I just place it inside  ``` response = client.get_users_mentions(client_id, since_id=start_id) ``` or should I use another function and pass in as a parameter? Can you provide an example that would work with my code?